# Display Posts by modifying the where clause only for my query

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I am trying to display posts that are 7 days old. For that i need to modify the 'where' clause as in code

```
//Hack found on the bottom of http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts
   function filter_where($where = '') {
        //posts in the last 7 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
    }
     ('posts_where', 'filter_where');
   query_posts($query_string);
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      ... and the usual
```

But doing this will modify all the queries, i just want to use this for one query in my plugin and i dont want to change any other query on my site. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to add the filter on the where clause, then just make sure you remove it using remove_filter() and the exact same signature **immediately after** you create the query.

In your example, you're using query_posts(), so add the filter, run your query, and then remove your filter right afterward.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where_filter', 10, 2 );
query_posts( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where_filter', 10, 2 );
```

It is to be noted that when you use the 2-argument version, the second argument can be of great use in limiting your filter to only affecting the queries you're interested in.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where_filter', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_where_filter( $where_clause, $query_object ){
  // check conditions on your query object...

  // ... then manipulate your $where_clause accordingly
  return $where_clause;
}
```

If you go that route, you can probably dispense with the remove_filter() altogether.

Further, you can probably dispense with `query_posts()` too, while you're at it. if you're already mucking around with `get_posts()` filters, which are run on every query, adding in another query with `query_posts()` is just going to slow down your blog load times.

So find a way to identify the page you're on (inspect the $query_object using `print_r()` to see what goodies it holds, or use a conditional like `is_main_query()` etc), then wrap your additional `WHERE` conditions within a big ol' `if{ }` block. Set up your filter NOT from the page template you're on, but rather from within your `functions.php`, or some included class. And of course **test, test, test** to make sure you're not affecting other pages of your site, or some widget, or your RSS feed, or the admin back end.